# Java - Why is my Serializable object file size so large?

Tags: java, image, serialization, filesize

So I have an image, called `square.png`, that is about 3.7 kB in size. I read it into a BufferedImage as so:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read("square.png");
```

At this point I tried writing several different objects to the disk.

```
ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("square_out.data"));
```

I tried the image wrapped in an ImageIcon: `stream.writeObject(new ImageIcon(img));`

I tried a 2D array of the same size as the pixel dimension of the image (800x600).

I tried wrapping that array in a custom class that implements Serializable and writing that.

All the above techniques resulted in a `square_out.data` with a size of about 1.9 MB. That's huge considering the original image was only a handful of kilobytes. It's also odd because the size was exactly the same for each. Is there any reasonable explanation for this/is there a way around it? I'd like to store lots of these, so the absurd file size is bothersome.

Comment: Did my post answer your question? If so, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, or otherwise elaborate on what you're after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `BufferedImage` stores the image in uncompressed format internally (and that is what gets serialized).

Use [`ImageIO.write`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) to save the image in compressed format.